# Why is mysql saying there is a syntax error?

Tags: mysql

I'm pretty new to the world of outer joins, and I'm trying to get used to them, but I have no idea why mysql is saying the syntax is incorrect. Does anyone care to give some insight?

```
SELECT * FROM user_courses, course_updates 
         WHERE user_courses.crn = course_updates.crn AND user_courses.user_id = 1
         LEFT JOIN followers ON (followers.followee = course_updates.user_id)
```

Answer (score 3):

The `LEFT JOIN` clause should become before the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT * FROM user_courses, course_updates 
         LEFT JOIN followers ON (followers.followee = course_updates.user_id)
         WHERE user_courses.crn = course_updates.crn AND user_courses.user_id = 1
```

By the way, you can also use `INNER JOIN for you other tables, so you don't have two types of syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM user_courses
         INNER JOIN course_updates on user_courses.crn = course_updates.crn 
         LEFT JOIN followers ON followers.followee = course_updates.user_id
         WHERE user_courses.user_id = 1
```

Note that I have omitted the parentheses around the `ON` condition, which is perfectly valid. Also, you can see that using `INNER JOIN`, you can specify the join conditions in the join itself, leaving the `WHERE` clause solely for filtering. I think this results in better readability of your query.

Answer (score 1):

Use like this

```
SELECT * FROM user_courses, course_updates 
LEFT JOIN followers ON (followers.followee = course_updates.user_id)
WHERE user_courses.crn = course_updates.crn AND user_courses.user_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Because there is a syntax error.

Try

```
SELECT * 
FROM    user_courses LEFT JOIN
        course_updates  ON  user_courses.crn = course_updates.crn 
                        AND user_courses.user_id = 1 LEFT JOIN 
        followers ON (followers.followee = course_updates.user_id)
```

From [enter link description here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

the `FROM table_references` comes before the `WHERE where_condition`

Also maybe look at [JOIN Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Comment: You actually changed the behaviour of the query, by using two left joins.

Comment: That could be lef to the OP. Making it an INNER JOIN should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Try This..

```
SELECT * FROM user_courses INNER JOIN course_updates ON user_courses.crn = course_updates.crn LEFT JOIN followers ON followers.followee = course_updates.user_id WHERE user_courses.user_id = 1
```

Since, `WHERE` clause will be used after `JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

Yes your syntax is wrong, in your case use **WHERE** clause at the end of the statement as follows:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    user_courses uc
        INNER JOIN course_updates cu ON cu.crn = uc.crn
        LEFT OUTER JOIN followers f ON f.followee = cu.USER_ID
WHERE   uc.USER_ID = 1
```

Also make sure f.followee type and cu.USER_ID are the same.

Hope this would help you!!!